# How to know control is handled or no inside user-control key-up event

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, controls, keyup

I have some UIElements in my UserControl. Some of them might be a multiline textbox some of them might not be. For example:

```
 <Usercontrol PreviewKeyDown="Wizard_PreviewKeyDown">
    <StackPanel>
      <TextBox/>
      <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True"/>
    </StackPanel>
 <Usercontrol>
```

Code behind of this control:

```
 private void Wizard_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
     Key key = (e.Key == Key.System ? e.SystemKey : e.Key);
     if (key == Key.Enter)
     {
         UIElement uiElement = (e.OriginalSource as UIElement);
         GoToNext(); //if uiElement is already handled I should not call this method
     }
 }
```

I should not call my GoToNext() method if uiElement is alredy handled. In this case if I select my first textbox and click Enter it should go to next because this textbox is not a multiline. If I select my second textbox it should not go next because it is a multiline. How can I know is UIElement Handled or not? Can someone help me with this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "handled"? I am not following

Comment: Try to check if uiElement is a `TextBox` and if so check the `AcceptsReturn` property.

Comment: thanks! I used KeyDown="Wizard_KeyDown" instead of PreviewKeyDown="Wizard_KeyDown" and it's working as I wanted

Comment: @Dilshod by hendled he means when you press enter key in textbox with AcceptsReturn is true, textbox will handle enter(it will enter new line), but when you press enter key in textbox with AcceptsReturn=false it will not handle and you should handle it in the UserControl keydown event subscriber

Comment: @Jamaxack thanks that's right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used KeyDown="Wizard_KeyDown" instead of PreviewKeyDown="Wizard_PreviewKeyDown" and it's working as I wanted.